# CSV shopify regarding multiple rows for image urls

Tags: vba, csv

I am trying to edit my Etsy CSV file to import to shopify.
The problem I am having is that Etsy CSV shows multiple images as separate columns where as shopify can show them in rows and not columns.

Right now, I have created a separate column and manually add how many images the row has and I want to use this number so I can write a piece of VBA code that will automatically create how many rows for the same product handle, which will enable me to easily add my images in.
Is this the best way to do it? or is there a quicker way?

I want it so that if the product has 3 images, it would create 3 rows and place the image url in each of the 3 rows. image 1 in row 1, image 2 in row 2 and image 3 in row 3. then automatically move to the next row and check how many rows are needed etc..

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the desired input and output format would be helpful...you do not mention what the Etsy file delimiter is (I assume it is a comma since it is a CSV file).

The following code will take a CSV file with a row format, separated by commas:
URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4,URL5,URL6,URL7

And write it to a new CSV file on your desktop in a column format:
URL1
URL2
URL3
URL4
URL5
URL6
URL7

Replace the text between the quotes in the **sUser** variable with your user name on your computer.

If the delimiter is not a comma, replace text between the quotes in the **sDelimiter** variable with the appropriate delimiter.

If you are unaware, you can enter a VBA editor by opening a program like Microsoft Excel or Word then press Alt+f11, paste this code in then hit the run button (play symbol).

It will ask you to select your Etsy file and tell you when the Shopify file has been written to your Desktop.

```
Sub EtsyColumnToRow()
Dim sUser as String
sUser = "Your name on your computer"
Dim sDelimiter As String
sDelimiter = ","

Dim oEtsyFile 'Object used to get the Etsy file
Dim oFSO    'Access computers files with FileSystemObject
Dim oInput  'CSV file
Dim sTemp   'CSV file after it is converted to a string
Dim oTextstream 'Open Etsy file as a textstream
Const ForReading = 1
Const TristateUseDefault = -2
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'User picks the file from a file explorer window
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog( _
FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogOpen)
With dlgOpen
    .Title = "Select Etsy File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.csv", 1 'force them to pick csv files
    .Show
End With

'If the user did not pick the file, you cannot proceed
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
sPath = dlgOpen.SelectedItems.Item(1)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected!" & vbCrLf & "Exiting Macro", vbInformation, "Etsy to Shopify"
    Exit Sub
End If

'if the macro gets to this point, they picked a file to open in the section above
'Get the file and set variables to read the file
Set oEtsyFile = oFSO.GetFile(sPath)
Set oTextstream = oEtsyFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
Set oInput = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sPath, ForReading) 'Open CSV file
sTemp = oInput.ReadAll          'Read in the CSV data
sSplit = Split(sTemp, sDelimiter)   'Split CSV by comma character to determine how many URLs are in it

Dim iRowCount As Integer
iRowCount = UBound(sSplit) + 1     'Count the number of Etsy rows

oEtsyFile.Close 'Close the Etsy file

Dim oShopifyFile 'Object for Shopify file

'replace special characters in current date and time to add to unique file names
sNow = Replace(Now, "/", "_")
sNow = Replace(sNow, ":", "_")
sSplit1 = Split(oEtsyFile.name, ".")
sShopifyFileName = "Shopify_" & sSplit1(0) & "_" & sNow & ".csv"
sShopifyFolder = "C:\Users\" & sUser & "\Desktop\"
sReportPath = sShopifyFolder & sShopifyFileName

Set oShopifyFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(sReportPath) 'Create a new shopify file

For i = 0 To iRowCount - 1
    If i <> iRowCount - 1 Then
        oShopifyFile.writeline sSplit(i) 'Writeline adds a return
    Else
        oShopifyFile.write sSplit(i) 'Write does not add a return
    End If
Next

oShopifyFile.Close 'close the file
MsgBox "Shopify file written to Desktop" 'DONE!
```

End Sub